# Weird routes being generated by routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

This is my routers.rb

Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resource :products
end
```

but generated routes are missing the :id

```
GET    /products(.:format)                               products#show
PATCH  /products(.:format)                               products#update
PUT    /products(.:format)                               products#update
DELETE /products(.:format)                               products#destroy
```

I had some configuration changes before (changed from using grape back to using the conventional rails api) - could that be why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :products
end
```

Read [Singular Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources).

Comment: ah! did not know there was a difference!